# How to count certain characters in c#?

Tags: c#, replace, textbox

Im new to C# and I need to make a program that can  count these characters (š, ž, č) in a textbox. I put the replace method in but it says No overload for method "Replace" takes 3 arguments. I figured out that the Replace method can't take 3 arguments. The problem is that I don't know what other code I can use. Can anybody help?

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblDolzinaStavka.Text = txtBesedilo.Text.Length.ToString();

    int Sumniki = txtBesedilo.Text.Length - txtBesedilo.Text.Replace("š", "č", "ž").Length;
}
```

Comment: Well what would you expect the `Replace` method to do here? You're not looking for a replacement - you're looking for a count.

Comment: I guess he is trying to replace the chars with void and calculate the length difference from the initial string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Replace` is used to replace one character or string within a string with another. For example, `"mum".Replace("u", "o")` will return `"mom"`. That's not counting occurrences of anything - it's not the method you want at all.

It sounds like you want something like:

```
// Replace "foo" with a more meaningful name - we don't know what the
// significance of these characters is.
int foo = txtBesedilo.Text.Count(c => c == 'š' || c == 'č' || c == 'ž');
```

Or:

```
char[] characters = { 'š', 'č', 'ž' };
int foo = txtBesedilo.Text.Count(c => characters.Contains(c));
```

Both of these snippets use the [`Enumerable.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535181.aspx) extension method which counts how many items in a collection match a certain condition. In this case the "items in a collection" are "characters in `txtBesedilo.Text`" and the condition is whether or not it's one of the characters you're interested in.

Comment: isn't the second solution going to perform 1 search in `characters` per char in `txtBesedilo` (being quite less interesting than `.Count`) ?

Comment: @quantdev: Yes, it is - which will be pretty fast, given how small the array is. It's probably slightly less efficient than the hardcoded version, but more flexible. (You can specify the set of characters elsewhere, pass it into the method or whatever.)

Answer (score 3):

```
int count = txtBesedilo.Text.Count(a => a == 'š' || a == 'č' || a == 'ž')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ :

```
int result = txtBesedilo.Text.Count(x => (x == 'š' || x == 'ž' || x == 'č' ));
```